# How to refresh Android mobile GPS state

Tags: android, gps

I use the Android mobile phone to location in the outdoor, back to the interior, there is not the GPS signal. here call `getLastKnownLocation()` to return location result is the last time's. The fact is the (indoors) has no GPS signal. How do I refresh GPS state ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are testing in indoor try to use both   from network and gps satelite(Note:Location information from network sometimes not 100% accurate)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

and wait sometime for getting a gps fix from gps-reciver.normaly it takes 2 to 3 minutes if there is less signal strength it may take long.

if you are facing any problem please put your code we will check

Answer (score 0):

As the Abhijit said, you can use those code lines when you are outside or near window to fetch the GPS Co-ordinates.

However when you are inside the room or basement and you still want to find the GPS Co-ordinates, you can try this alternate way,

When you are in basement or in room you are still getting network coverage ( network signals ). So here you can use TelePhony API to get the GPS Co-Ordinates.

```
String mcc;  //Mobile Country Code
String mnc;  //mobile network code
String cellid; //Cell ID
String lac;  //Location Area Code

//retrieve a reference to an instance of TelephonyManager
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation)telephonyManager.getCellLocation();
String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();

cellid = String.valueOf( cellLocation.getCid() );
lac = String.valueOf( cellLocation.getLac() );
mcc = networkOperator.substring( 0, 3 );
mnc = networkOperator.substring( 3 );
```

Now passing this cellid,lac,mcc and mnc values to [opencellid.org](http://www.opencellid.org/) you will the latitude & longitude values.

Answer (score 0):

You can initate your Service  every 5 Minutes according to your need 
You can use a `pending Intent`

```
long UPDATE_INTERVAL=300000;
        Intent myIntent=new Intent(Main.this,YourGPSLOcationClass.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getService(Main.this,0,myIntent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),UPDATE_INTERVAL,pendingIntent);
```